# How to fix continuous __webpack_hmr calls in Angular?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular5, webpack-4, webpack-hmr

I have an application on .NetCore + Angular, It is build using webpack. There is no angular cli. On deployment to production, I am getting continous network calls by __webpack_hmr. I have deployed minified production build in angular. Is there any fix or is it normal ?

Here is the [Image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18YZ7VoP03l7Q7BI1JoWHlrfPQvQCc9CT) -

We were getting so many network calls recorded in Azure Telemetry. On searching the reason, I found there are so many calls by __webpack_hmr

Comment: Do you have a hot reload on your project ?

Comment: Yes.. But I don't know how to turn off.. I am also unable to find from where it is implemented!

Comment: Can't help you without any code, but it's certainly that hot reload that makes such requests.